# Rewriting basis of vector in terms of another another basis vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

So I'm currently studying linear algebra and came across an example from the textbook which I don't understand. The example is: Let $V=\mathbf{R}^2$ and let $\beta$  be the basis consisting of the vectors $u_1$ = $(1, 1)$ and $u_2 = (1, — 1)$  and $\beta \prime$ be the basis consisting of the vectors $u_1 \prime = (1,2)$ and $u_2 \prime = ( — 2, 1)$. If $v$ is any vector in $V$, then $v$ can be expressed uniquely as $v = x_1 u_1 + x_2u_2$, and also uniquely as $v = x_1\prime u_1\prime +  x_2\prime u_2\prime$

I don't have any problem understanding the part above but what I don't get is the following:

Notice that $u_1$  and $u_2 $ in particular can be expressed in terms of $u_1 \prime$ and $u_2 \prime$
:

$u_1 = (3/5)u_1\prime - ( 1 / 5 )u_2\prime$ and $u_2 = ( - 1 / 5 ) u_1\prime - (3 /5 )u_2\prime$

The textbook skips the steps to show how $u_1$ and $u_2$ are rewritten in terms of $u_1 \prime$ and $u_2 \prime$ and I'm confused to how it's possible. Could someone help me with the hidden step and break down how  $u_1$ and $u_2$ are expressed in terms of $u_1 \prime$ and $u_2 \prime$

Comment: using matrices to change coordinates:  $\pmatrix{1&-2\\2&1}^{-1}\pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1}=\dfrac15 \pmatrix{3&-1\\-1&-3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathcal{B}' = \{u'_{1},u'_{2}\}$ is a basis, we can particularly express $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ in terms of it.

More precisely, one has that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
u_{1} = (1,1) = a_{11}u'_{1} + a_{12}u'_{2} = (a_{11} - 2a_{12},2a_{11} + a_{12})\\\\
u_{2} = (1,-1) = a_{21}u'_{1} + a_{22}u'_{2} = (a_{21} - 2a_{22},2a_{21} + a_{22})
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

When you solve such systems of equations, you get the desired relation.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We use this property: any $v\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ could be expressed as a linear combination of $u_1’$ and $u_2’$.
So $$
u_1=λ_1u_1’+μ_1u_2’$$
$$u_2=λ_2u_1’+μ_2u_2’
$$
And this leads to
$$1=λ_1-2μ_1$$
$$1=2λ_1+μ_1$$
$$1=λ_2-2μ_2$$
$$-1=2λ_2+μ_2$$
By solving these equations, we get
$$λ_1=\frac{3}{5},λ_2=-\frac{1}{5}$$
$$μ_1=-\frac{1}{5},μ_2=-\frac{3}{5}$$
That’s exactly what we get finally.